# Saving text in a local file in Internet Explorer 10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I need to be able to save a string into a local file. Based on the code in [here](http://thiscouldbebetter.wordpress.com/2012/12/18/loading-editing-and-saving-a-text-file-in-html5-using-javascrip/) I got the following going:

```
function saveTextAsFile(fileNameToSaveAs, textToWrite) {
var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {
    type: 'text/plain'
});

var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";

if (true) { //window.webkitURL !== null) {
    // Chrome allows the link to be clicked
    // without actually adding it to the DOM.
    downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
} else {
    // Firefox requires the link to be added to the DOM
    // before it can be clicked.
    downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
    downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
    downloadLink.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
}

downloadLink.click();
}
```

This works fine for Chrome and Firefox, but not for Internet Explorer 10 as

```
downloadLink.click();
```

gives:

```
SCRIPT5: Access is denied.
```

Is there any explanation/solution to this ?

thanks!

Comment: Old question but ran into this myself.  To get rid of the 'Access is denied' you may have to add your site to the 'Trusted Sites' in the security window.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Thx to mstubna, here is a solution for Chrome, FF, and IE>9:

```
function saveTextAsFile(fileNameToSaveAs, textToWrite) {
  /* Saves a text string as a blob file*/  
  var ie = navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE\s([\d.]+)/),
      ie11 = navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident\/7.0/) && navigator.userAgent.match(/rv:11/),
      ieEDGE = navigator.userAgent.match(/Edge/g),
      ieVer=(ie ? ie[1] : (ie11 ? 11 : (ieEDGE ? 12 : -1)));

  if (ie && ieVer<10) {
    console.log("No blobs on IE ver<10");
    return;
  }

  var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {
    type: 'text/plain'
  });

  if (ieVer>-1) {
    window.navigator.msSaveBlob(textFileAsBlob, fileNameToSaveAs);

  } else {
    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
    downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
    downloadLink.onclick = function(e) { document.body.removeChild(e.target); };
    downloadLink.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    downloadLink.click();
  }
}
```

Comment: Understandable, clear, well-formatted, minimizable. Oh, and it works.

Answer (score 33):

IE 10 and 11 use a distinct syntax for downloading or saving blobs to the client machine. Once you've created a blob, use:

```
window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, 'file.txt');
```

or

```
window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, 'file.txt');
```

to trigger the file save or file save/open dialog.

For more info, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673542(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 9):

For modern browsers solution goes like this, tested: IE11, FF & Chrome

```js
var csvData = new Blob([arg.data], {type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;'});
//IE11 & Edge
if (navigator.msSaveBlob) {
 navigator.msSaveBlob(csvData, exportFilename);
} else {
 //In FF link must be added to DOM to be clicked
 var link = document.createElement('a');
 link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(csvData);
 link.setAttribute('download', exportFilename);
 document.body.appendChild(link); 
 link.click();
 document.body.removeChild(link); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

plus for ie EDGE:

```
var ieEDGE = navigator.userAgent.match(/Edge/g);
if (ie || ie11 || ieEDGE) {
    if (ieVer>9 || ieEDGE) {
        var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {
            type: 'text/plain'
        });
        window.navigator.msSaveBlob(textFileAsBlob, fileName);
    } else {
        console.log("No supported on IE ver<10");
    }
} else { ... }
```

Comment: Edge did actually work for me without using window.navigator

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/#supported-browsers) library to achieve that. Easy to use, takes care of browser types and versions.
There is an [AngularJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-file-saver) version available as well.