# Downloading a zip file using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, content-type

I'm trying to implement the download of a file through angular.js
The file comes from the server in binary format, the content type is `application/octet-stream`

The download is a GET using `$resource`. Looking at the parameter passed to the callback (called `content` below), it's an object containing the byte array and also a list of properties for `$resource`.

Tried several ways to serve the file, but without success.

First of them:

```
...
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = "data:attachment/zip," + content;
a.download = zipName;
a.click();
```

In this case, the content of the zip file is `[object Object]`

I tried extracting the array from the object and joining everything into a string variable. The zip file in this case is way larger than the normal size. I had to set `isArray: true` in the service that calls `$resource`, otherwise there was no way to extract the byte content from the response object.

Here is how I did it:

```
var str = '';
for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
   str += content[i][0];
}

...
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = "data:attachment/zip," + str;
a.download = zipName;
a.click();
```

Worth mentioning that calling `encodeURI` on `str` increments drastically the size of the downloaded zip, but the archive remains invalid.

I also tried creating a `Blob` from the `str` and setting the content type to `application/octet-stream`, without any luck.

```
var blob = new Blob([str], {'type':"application/octet-stream"});
a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
...
```

Don't know what I'm missing here, but it looks rather a problem of getting the right format for the byte array content and setting the correct `href` before simulating the click for downloading.

Help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: remember that you can run into download problems with IE11 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18755750/saving-text-in-a-local-file-in-internet-explorer-10/20927897#20927897

Answer (score 2):

I just found your post and fixed an answer using what you enlist.

- First you have to ensure that your angular $http request includes, like the following get example (`include responseType: 'arraybuffer'`)

  ```
  $http.get('/downloadZip', {
              params: {
                  file: encodeURIComponent(filepath)
              },
              responseType: 'arraybuffer'
  //your code
  ```
- Second on your success or promise handler you should change your `window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)` to `URL.createObjectURL(blob)`. Implementing something similar to the following:

  ```
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  var blob = new Blob([data], {'type':"application/octet-stream"});
  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  a.download = "filename.zip";
  a.click();
  ```

With these you are creating a new anchor element and simulating to opening it. With a correct Blob creation since the request had been modified correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Angular is no needed.

```
var zip_file_path = "" //put inside "" your server path with file.zip
var zip_file_name = "" //put inside "" file name or something
var a = document.createElement("a");
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.style = "display: none";
a.href = zip_file_path;
a.download = zip_file_name;
a.click();
document.body.removeChild(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is still on AngularJS (like me) and wants to do this, I took David's answer and made it work with the angular $resource instead of using the lower level $http directly.  If you use $resource, this should help you:

```
    var myReportingResource = $resource(baseURL + '/mypath/:command', {},{
        getExportZip: {
            method: 'GET',
            params: {
                command: 'exportzip'
            },
            responseType: 'arraybuffer',
            // don't try to convert the zip to JSON
            // instead take the data that comes back and put it in an object under a content key
            transformResponse: function(data){
                return {content: data};
            }
        }
    });

    // call the resource like this
    myReportingResource.getExportZip(yourParams).$promise.then(function(zipData){
            // create a anchor element, stick the zip data in it, and click it to download
            var anchor = angular.element('<a/>');
            anchor.attr({
                href: URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([zipData.content], {'type':'application/octet-stream'})),
                download: 'myfilename.zip'
            })[0].click();

        });
```

You need the `transformResponse` bit because otherwise AngularJS will convert your response to JSON- which is wrong with binary data.  This is why later you use `zipData.content` to pass the data into the Blob.  You can get rid of the `content` part, it's there for simplicity with my error handling code.

This works in Chrome and Safari as of May 2019.  Didn't test anywhere else.