# How can I make my file download work on IE and safari?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, safari

I'm trying to create and download a file on client side with the following code:

```
function downloadFile(filename, text) {
    var pom = document.createElement('a');
    pom.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
    pom.setAttribute('download', filename);
    pom.click();
}
```

Although this only works on chrome. Nothing happens on safari and IE. How can I make it work?

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18755750/saving-text-in-a-local-file-in-internet-explorer-10

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if youve figured this out or not but for this to work in safari you need to create an event and dispatch on the created element like this:

```
    var downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
    downloadLink.setAttribute('href', 'data:application/octet;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(data));
    downloadLink.setAttribute('download', fileName);
    downloadLink.style.display = "none";
    downloadLink.onclick = function (event) {
        document.body.removeChild(event.target);
    };

    var clk = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
    clk.initEvent("click", true, true);
    downloadLink.dispatchEvent(clk);

    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    downloadLink.dispatchEvent(clk);`
```

Answer (score -1):

I used this to save my file in CSV/excel format and works in chrome/IE/Safari
refer and make changes needed

```
        var fileName = name + "["+ name1 +"]";
        var uri = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + escape(finalResult);
        var link = document.createElement("a");    
        link.href = uri;
        link.style = "visibility:hidden";
        link.download = fileName + ".csv";
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
        location.reload();
```

Comment: Hi, this doesn't work on safari or IE still. I've copy pasted your code and made changes to filename and finalResult, but nothing happens on IE or safari. :(