# Angular App getting Access Denied from IE11 when going through Intranet

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, proxy, intranet

This is a weird problem and I apologize beforehand that I may not give enough details:

We have a pretty standard Angular app that needs to access an API on a different (sub-)domain, using CORS. Everything works perfectly fine on Chrome and Firefox. 
We also got it working on IE >=9.

Unfortunately, some of our customers need to access our public website from within their company intranet. In this case, using IE, only a couple API requests go through. 
Chrome and Firefox cause no problems.

- They can create a session
- They get the result of a second GET request
- But the third request fails

In the console, we see an Access Denied message caused by a GET request.

**AND**: When they reload the page, the third request goes through. 
One customer could bypass his intranet and access our website directly. 
Then, everything worked like a charm.

Please note that we are only aware of issues with IE 11.
Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: surely the message is more verbose than just *"Access Denied"*

Comment: Unfortunately, it isn't. It says "Access Denied", followed by an application stack trace. However, your question made me ask Google another time, and I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28740949/access-is-denied-on-ie11-in-angularjs. Maybe should update our Angular version  from 1.3x to 1.4.x?