# Error: access denied on anchor tag click - while trying to download file in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have file content as byte array which is returnedfrom API controller. when a anchor tag is clicked I would like to download the content as file in the respective format like doc/docx/pdf. I'm using IE11 - HTML5 download attribute is not supported in IE11.
Please suggest me a solution.

Here is the code I have used:

```
function(data, status) {
    if (data != null) {
        var blob = new Blob([data.FileContent], {
            type: 'application/pdf'
        });
        var downloadurl = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);

        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = downloadurl;
        //a.download = "content.txt" as IE doesn't support download attribute
        a.target = "_blank";
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click(); // here it throws error access denied
        document.body.removeChild(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please help me in solving this.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20927897/1291428