# Access denied on File download in Edge

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I have a request to a web api that returns a file. I have the following javascript that places the file data in a link which then starts the download:

```
        function (response) {
            $scope.downloadStarted = false;
            var file = new Blob([response.data], {
                type: 'application/csv'
            });
            var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            var installer = document.createElement('a');
            installer.href = fileURL;
            installer.target = '_blank';
            installer.download = 'Installer.EXE';
            document.body.appendChild(installer);
            installer.click();
        }
```

I see the data come in and it fails on the click. This works correctly in Chrome/Firefox.

The following is the error that is thrown in the console:

[image]

This is happening in Edge.

Comment: What version of IE? Does the console say anything about the problem?

Comment: @MaxArt updated question.

Comment: It may be possible that Edge prevents downloading .exe files that come from an insecure source.

Comment: To test @MaxArt's theory, you should take Angular out of the equation. Create a basic HTML file that only contains the `<a>` tag, and click on it in Edge. See what happens.

Comment: Ah, found the same question with the correct answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18755750/saving-text-in-a-local-file-in-internet-explorer-10