# download HTML 5 attribute is not working properly in IE 11

Tags: javascript, html

I have a anchor tag as follows:-

```
<a id="lnkAvailabilityBrochure" href="" style="visibility:hidden" download></a>
```

and the click event of a div is bound to the following method that simulates clicking the above hyperlink:-

```
var downloadPropertyBrochure = function () {
        if (propertyBrochure.BrochureId != EmptyGuid){
            $("#lnkPropertyBrochure").attr("href", propertyBrochure.ViewUrl);
            $("#lnkPropertyBrochure")[0].click();
        }
        else
        {
            $.growlUI("There is no brochure to download..");
        }
    }
```

This works just fine in chrome and also in IE 11 it opens the download but IN THE SAME WINDOW !! How can I prevent this. How can I force download and not allow to open in the same page. Any ideas ?

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18755750/saving-text-in-a-local-file-in-internet-explorer-10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the download attribute is not supported by IE 11:

https://caniuse.com/#search=download

Comment: thats correct. IE 13 is the first version that supports it. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp